# Xcode: How to disable the crosshair, when pressing alt?

Tags: xcode

Every time I press 'alt' in Xcode a crosshair for text selection appears. I can't use the shortcuts for commits and code folding anymore. Is there a way to disable it?

XCode 14.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over [here](https://www.lilback.com/option-clicking-issues-in-xcode/) I found the following command for the terminal:
`defaults write com.apple.Xcode NSProhibitMultipleTextSelectionByMouse -bool YES` With this the most shortcuts are working again (the only one still not working is ⌥⌘C for commits)

Answer (score 1):

Just **disable this shortcut** in Xcode's preferences.

Navigate to Xcode's preferences from the menu bar. In the "Key Bindings" tab, look for the "*Option Key Behaviour*" section<sup>1</sup> and, from the drop-down menu, select "*Use Option as Meta key*". It should disable the crosshair text selection behaviour when pressing the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>  key.

With this shortcut disabled, you will not have the issue you're experiencing.

**Note:** Modifying keyboard shortcuts in Xcode (as well as in any app) may affect other commands, so it's important to choose a keyboard shortcut that ***doesn't conflict with existing ones***.

<sup><sup>1</sup> In this section, you should see two options: "Use Option as Meta key" and "Use Option as Standard Modifier". The first option will disable the crosshair text selection behaviour and allow you to use other keyboard shortcuts (requiring <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> ). The second option will keep the crosshair text selection behaviour while disabling other keyboard shortcuts that use the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>  key. So, use make sure you select the first option.</sup>

Comment: somehow I can't find anything searching for "alternative selection" or "alt" in Key Binding. My Key Binding Set is set to default and "adapt to current keyboard" is checked.

Comment: @buleva My mistake, it's called "Option Key Down". Or "Option Key (alt) Down".

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I also can't find "option key down". I'm on XCode 14.3.1

Comment: @buleva Yes. My bad. I cannot seem to find this keyboard shortcut neither. While there is apparently no way to disable this crosshair text selection behaviour, you can choose to use the Option key as a Meta key which will ultimately disable the crosshair text selection behaviour and allow you to use other keyboard shortcuts.